# How do you close the tmux list-keys screen?

Tags: tmux, freebsd

In tmux, after pressing the prefix key (Ctrl + b in my case) and then pressing question mark to go to the list-keys screen, how do you close out of the list-keys screen and return back to whatever you were doing?

Comment: try to press `q` key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `list-keys` directly in the client (as opposed to from the command line, as is done in the examples below), *tmux* uses its “copy mode” to display the output. You should be able to use <kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to end the copy mode instance. If your `mode-keys` is `emacs`, then you can also use <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

You can check the bindings yourself by looking for the keys that are bound to `cancel` in the tables for the copy mode.

```
% for e in vi emacs; do tmux list-keys -t "$e"-copy; done | grep cancel
bind-key -t vi-copy    C-c cancel
bind-key -t vi-copy      q cancel
bind-key -t emacs-copy     C-c cancel
bind-key -t emacs-copy  Escape cancel
bind-key -t emacs-copy       q cancel
```

You can tell which of the tables are in use by checking your `mode-keys`:

```
% for o in w gw; do tmux show-option -"$o" mode-keys; done | head -1
mode-keys emacs
```